# How to add many-to-many relation using stateless session in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, stateless

I have two entities mapped to DB using NHibernate:

```
class Entity1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Entity2[] ReferencedEntities { get; set; }
}

class Entity2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

For Entity1 I also specify many-to-many relation to Entity2:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.ReferencedEntities);
```

As I understand, internally NHibernate represents many-to-many relation creating some relation entity like:

```
class Reference
{
    public Entity1 Entity1 { get; set; }
    public Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm adding those entities to DB using NHibernate stateless session like this:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
{
    session.Insert(entity1);
    foreach (var entity2 in entity1.ReferencedEntities)
    {
        session.Insert(entity2);
    }
}
```

But I also want to add relation between them. For this, I need to save relation entity as well. How can I add many-to-many relation using stateless session? Do I need to specify relation entity implicitly or there is some another way?

Comment: Why don't you use an ISession? There will be an actual link table in the database, your stateless session code, won't create those necessary link table rows.

Comment: Session has nothing common with data schema - it is only way of using it. Stateless session gives much better performance, as stateful session makes some unnecessary selects.

Comment: Nothing common with data schema? Not sure what that means. I suppose if you really really need to use only stateless session, then you'll have to map the many-to-many link table yourself and insert those rows. You're really working against NH though...might as well use ADO.net?

Answer (score 0):

Stateless session doesnt cascade operations so it wont save changes and links to the arrayelements if they are performed in other tables.

Unnecessary selects are often a sign of missing/wrong code like `UnsavedValue()` or ``` Equals()``GetHashCode() ```